# VIM: How to move cursor in empty lines?

Tags: vim

I've been through a lot of instructions, but I can't find a solution to this problem. Giving this code in vim as an example:

```
#include <iostream>

 <--- My cursor is here

int main(){
std::cout << "Hello world";
return 0;
}
```

My cursor is stuck in the position above (I can't press `h` or `k`). So I want to be able to press `h` and `k` (moving my cursor forward and backward in an empty line), what could I do to allow this?

Thank you so much for reading all this.

Comment: FWIW, `k` moves the cursor upward. To move the cursor to the right, use `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

Read the documentation for details on the other options available:

```
:help virtualedit
```

From the docs: "Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is no actual character."

Comment: Thank you so much, this totally solves my problem!